# Как работает char* r?

Tags: c, строки

Насколько я понял он помещает строку в read-only секцию , что означает что контент нельзя модифицировать. Можете объяснить почему он позволяет изменять контент во втором случае?

Example:
  `char *r = "Hello world";

r[0]='J'; //(1 случай и я понимаю почему оно не изменяется)

r="Changed"; //(2 случай. Почему в этом случае содержимое меняется?)`

Answer (score 3):

Потому что во втором случае вы не пытаетесь изменить строку, вы изменяете сам адрес, куда указывает указатель. Т.е. сначала он указывал на начало строки "Hello world", а затем начал указывать на начало строки "Changed".

Answer (score 1):

Фактически эта запись

```
char *r = "Hello world";
```

Компилятором преобразуется

```
const char <неименованый массив>[] = "Hello world";
char *r = <неименованый миассив>;
```

И компилятор помешает `<неименованый массив>` в секцию **.rodata** . 
 А указатель `r` в секцию **.bss**

Эта запись в более корректном написании

```
const char ra[] = "Hello world";
char *r = ra;
```

Но в этом случаи при попытатся присвоить

```
r[0] = 'J';
```

Компилятор предупридит о записи в память только для чтения.

Но если в программе написать

```
char ra[] = "Hello world";
char *r = ra;
```

Компилятор поместит  массив в секцию **.data** 
И данная операция будет корректна

```
r[0] = 'J';
```

Но в разных компиляторах возможно разное поведение. Данное поведение характерно для **gcc**.